# Save a block of data from memory to byte array to restore later the block from byte array

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
typedef struct {
    struct {
        uint64_t key;
        uint64_t hash;
        uint64_t size;
        uint64_t body;
    } length;
} block_head;

-----------------------------------------------------
//Block allocation

uint64_t d1, d2, d4; //Lengths for octet strings to be saved in memory block
uint64_t d3; //just for saving a size - integer value

unsigned char **data = (unsigned char**)malloc(sizeof(block_head) + d1 + d2 + d4);
block_head *head = (block_head *)data;
head->length.key = d1;
head->length.hash = d2;
head->length.size = d3;
head->length.body = d4;
-----------------------------------------------------
//Later we fill memory of data block

// get a pointer key buffer location
unsigned char *d = (char *)data + sizeof(secure_head_t);

//Add octet string
FillData1(d);

// get a pointer to the body buffer location
unsigned char *body = (unsigned char *)data + (sizeof(block_head) + head->length.d1 + head->length.d2);
//get the length of the body free space (of a block)
int body_length = head->length.body;

//body is filled with octet string, and length is saved to body_length
FillBody2((unsigned char*)body, &body_length) 

// Advance the body pointer to the location of the remaining space, and calculate just how much room is still available.

body += body_length;

// Save another octet string to block
FillBody3((unsigned char *)data + (sizeof(block_head) + head->length.key), &body_length);
```

Now I need to save the filled block `(unsigned char **data)` to a byte array, to restore later from array to a block.

I do this but it is not working:

```
unsigned char **data = some_filled_data;

block_head *head = (block_head *)data;

// convert data to arr

unsigned char *arr = (unsigned char *)malloc( sizeof(block_head) + (head->length.key + head->length.hash + head->length.body));
memcpy(&arr, data, sizeof(block_head) + (head->length.key + head->length.hash + head->length.body));

// convert arr to data

unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*)malloc( sizeof(unsigned char) * strlen(arr));
memcpy(&data, &arr, strlen(arr));
```

If I try to use the new converted block from `arr`, then I will get an error, because it is not constructed correctly or something like this

How I should convert correctly data to `arr` and `arr` to data, to represent the same block ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I could not decipher the description, this answers the title:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    char b[20];
} Test;

void fillAndBackupTest(char **out) {
    Test test;
    test.a = 20;
    strcpy(test.b, "Hello!");
    *out = (char*) malloc(sizeof Test);
    memcpy(*out, &test, sizeof Test);
}

void restoreAndPrintTest(char *in) {
    Test test;
    memcpy(&test, in, sizeof Test);
    printf("a: %d, b: %s\n", test.a, test.b);
}

int main()
{
    char *blob;
    fillAndBackupTest(&blob);
    restoreAndPrintTest(blob);
    free(blob);
    return 0;
}
```

A structure type, `Test` is defined, `fillAndBackupTest()` creates one, fills its fields and stores a "copy" of it into a buffer it allocates for itself (it is a `char*` for now, but actually it could very well remain being `void*`), then `restoreAndPrintTest()` restores a (different) `Test` instance from this buffer and prints its contents.

What you do with `malloc`-ing a sum of a size and some arbitrary numbers (`key`? `body`?) does not seem to be a good idea, and `strlen` can not measure the length of a binary blob either.